# Is it possible to doing a rolling Update of a nodePort service?

Tags: kubernetes

I investigate this point since a few days but didn't find an answer. My plan is to do a zero downtime change of a target Port.

May some of you have faced this before and now if this is possible, thanks for all answers.

Martin.

Comment: Never tried but this should work.
1. Add new port entry to your service with new nodePort. Don't delete the old port. Now, you should be able to access the service via both nodePort.
2. Update your app to use the new nodePort.
3. Delete the old port entry from the service.

Always try in a test cluster before doing in production.

Comment: @EmruzHossain if you already tested it, what do you think to post it as an answer?

Comment: @koopakiller I haven't tested it. So, I am not sure whether it work or not. If I get confirmation from Martin Mali that it worked, I will post it as answer.

Comment: @EmruzHossain thanks for your answer, I will test it as soon as I find the time.

Comment: @MartinMali Please let us know if any update here. Is the test successful without downtime?

Comment: @DevOps not with this method, but i found another method(in my Answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Solution that worked for me is to use the name of the port in target Port and change the Ports in the deployment itself. So the service do not have a downtime.